# Form with associations from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Given that I have the following associations:

```
Restaurants -> belongs_to -> City
Restaurants -> has_many -> Menus
```

I want that, when a User visits the /menus page, he will be shown a drop down with the cities that are in the system.  Once a city is selected, all the menus of all the restaurants from that city should be shown.

My question is: How would I create the form in order to associate the city with the menu model?  Right now I just have the drop down of the city, but later I would like to add restaurant categories to that search form too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you will need an association like,

class City < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :menus, through => :restaurants

end

Comment: I am not asking about the kind of association I want. I am asking about how to create the form.

Comment: ok, one question here. can user select a menu directly on the basis of city ?